# Check return value of command in if bash statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, return-value

I have a simple script that tries to curl and URL and echo a string if it failed or succeeded. But I get the following warnings, depending on how I form this if statement.

Depending on the quotes I use in the statement below I get the following warnings:

```
: -ne: unary operator expected
: integer expression expected
```

With the alternative check (as comment), I get the following error

`((: != 0 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "!= 0 ")`

The script:

```
c=`curl -s -m 10 https://example.com` || ce=$?

#if (( ${je} != 0 )); then 
if [ ${ce} -ne 0 ]; then 
        echo "Failed"
else
        echo "Succeeded"
fi
```

How do I correctly check the return value of the curl command in a bash if-statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you only set the exit status when the curl command fails.
If the command succeeds, then variable `ce` is not set (and also not quoted) and the test executes `if [ -ne 0 ]; then` and prints the error message.
Quoting the variable alone wouldn't help in this case, you would just get a different error message.

To fix this, set variable `ce` after the curl command no matter what the exit status of the curl command is:

```
c=$(curl -s -m 10 https://example.com)
ce=$?
if [ "$ce" -ne 0 ]; then 
  echo "Failed"
else
  echo "Succeeded"
fi
```

Or shorter without exit status variable:

```
c=$(curl -s -m 10 https://example.com)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
  echo "Failed"
else
  echo "Succeeded"
fi
```

Comment: Even shorter: `if ! c=$(curl ...); then`